# Invasion of the Bullets

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

When browsing [Get a Stack Overflow Careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one) page (must be logged out of Careers to see the page, otherwise you'll reach your own profile) with IE 11, you'll see this:

> [image]

Not a pleasant sight. Can those bullets please be stopped from invading?

IE 11 vanilla, 100% zoom, no add ons, Windows 7.

Comment: Someone must be trying to kill Stack Overflow (and has bad aim).

Comment: I see it as the result of 4 people's tee shots, where the 'o' is the pin.

Comment: Thought it was the [bulette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulette).

Comment: @DeerHunter lol this reminds me I actually fought those in D&D games back when I was playing! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has been fixed. Thanks for letting us know about some stray bullets. ;)

---

**Edit:** *What was causing it?*

Since **tox123** asked, I'll comment that the problem seemed to be that the sidebar column didn't have a position assigned to it. The `li` bullets in the sidebar list had a `margin-left` assigned to them, but in IE (for some reason) it was assigning these positions to the overall container of `.content`. IDK why. Adding `position: relative;` to the sidebar fixed it though.

Comment: What was causing it?

Comment: @tox123 probably some stray non cross browser CSS.